# How to increase my Ajax Like Button Speed (Jquery + PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a Ajax Like Button. After clicking the like button, it takes around 800ms - 1100 ms to do the following things:

- Open `insertlike.php` page in the background using Jquery
- Add the like to database in `insertlike.php` page
- Confirm the like using JSON
- Turn the like button color into green.

But `Facebook's` and other website's Like button works very fast.

Facebook directly change the like button color on click or it only change after adding the like into database?

This is my code:

`index.php` code to make ajax request

```
$(".insertlike").submit(function(e) {

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    var form = $(this); 
    $.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("button").html(data.addremove + " Watchlist");
        $(form).children("input#addedornotsend").attr("value",data.addedornotsend); 

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
```

Code inside `insertlike.php`

```
<?php

// Add to Database code 

$response = new \stdClass();
$response->addremove = "".$addremove."";
$response->addedornotsend = "".$addedornotsend."";
die(json_encode($response));
```

Any way to insert the like button speed? Maybe some php cache trick or something like that? I am still newbie.

Edit: This is my server response time speed test:

[image]

Comment: So you are asking how facebooks like button functions... This would be down to you to investigate, for all we know the other sites you compare to might be using real time data like websockets. Without using those you have no choice but to wait for the ajax call and server-side to complete if you want to confirm the update.

Comment: You can paint the button imagining that everything went well and, once it is finished, if there is something wrong display an error message.

Comment: The code suggests you have an input with id `addedornotsend` on *every* like button.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes @Don'tPanic

Comment: @JoshPoor OK - that's invalid HTML, and while I don't think it is the cause of your performance problems, it will cause problems.  IDs should be unique, only 1 per page.

Comment: Why ID's should be unique? It is working perfectly fine because of `$(this)`.Should i change it into class??

Comment: [Because that's what an ID is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). If it really works it is random luck, it should not. Yes, you should change it to a class, that defines a "class" of similar items. I wonder if it even has some connection to your performance problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the **Event Based Architecture**. As soon as, user clicks on the like button, put the message in queue and then write to DB in background(Data Grid also can be a solution here, not sure if PHP has good data-grid solutions). And response to client will be sent back, assuming DB record is updated successfully.

https://martinfowler.com/articles/201701-event-driven.html

If you are updating single table, 800ms - 1100 ms does not seem to be acceptable timeline. Try to tune your SQL, check if the DB is properly tuned.Try to use ConnectionPool etc.

In Facebook, a. apart from updating the DB on like, b. It also does other background processing like generating the NewsFeeds to relevant parties etc. I am speculating that FB might be doing part b using events based architecture rather than keeping the user to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing `. submit()`, you should be doing `. click()`.

And what Facebook does is probably changing button's color right on click, without waiting for response. If the response results in error then probably the button's color is changed back to normal.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of that? Or is just a polite guess?

Comment: clicking on like button submit a form, so isn't it the same thing after all?

Comment: @Shirkam it's a guess (although I'm pretty confident, because liking never seemed long, even with throttled bandwidth).

Comment: @Josh Poor in this particular case, yes it is